# Android: ConstraintLayout, expected behavior upon setting visibility to Invisible for one of the views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have ConstraintLayout with 3 `textViews` and an `imageView` in it. And this is the recycler view item.

- First textView's top and left constraints are set to parent. Height and width are set to wrap_content.
- Second textView's start constraint is set toStart of the first textView and top is set toBottom of the first textView. with height and width set to wrap_content
- Third textView's start constraint is set toStart of the second textView and top is set toBottom of the second textView. with height and width set to wrap_content as well.

In some cases I have to hide the second textView. When I set `isVisible` to `false` for the second textView, the third textView moves up and is displayed in place of the second textView which is what I wanted in first place. But I don't understand why is it not overlapping with the first textview.

I suppose if we set isVisible to false for the textView in the middle, the textView below it, would lose its constraints and jump on top of the first textview and overlap with it. In my case it is working as expected but I don't understand why and how. Is this how `constraintLayout` supposed to work? Shouldn't I be using `barrier` for cases like this?
Please look at my xml code and the image. Thanks

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/default_card"
    android:background="cardBackground"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_8"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/size_8">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/size_16">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Address 1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Some street number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="CityState 88888" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

With second textView visible:
[image: With second textView visible:]

With second textView's isVisible set to false:
[image: With second textView's isVisible set to false]

Comment: Yes this is intended, constraints of `gone` views are still respected so layout doesn't break on visibility change. This is one of the advantages over `RelativeLayout` which actually doesn't know what to do when anchor view disappears.

Comment: So in my case, It is okay to not use barrier and just keep what I have?

Answer (score -2):

Use this Line
**Java**

```
textView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

**Kotlin**

```
textView2.visibility= View.INVISIBLE
```

Comment: How is it different than what I am doing? Just wondering.